# Как установить другую версию python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, установка, python-3.8

У меня стоит `pyhton 3.8`. Но мне нужно установить `pyhton 3.7` (на то есть причины). Нужно ли мне удалять `pyhton 3.8`, чтобы сделать это, и если нужно то как? Если что у меня операционная система Linux и модель `Linux Mint 18`.

Comment: Не модель, а дистрибутив

Comment: Можно через `pip` поставить всё что угодно и каких угодно версий в домашний каталог.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но мне нужно установить pyhton 3.7

Устанавливайте на здоровье. Только не "руками", а системным установщиком пакетов. Что там у вас - dnf / zypper / yum...

> Нужно ли мне удалять pyhton 3.8

Нет, не нужно

> и если нужно то как?

На самом деле, Вам **нужно** разобраться с тем, какая программа на питоне какой **конкретный** интерпретатор питона использует. До сих пор есть много приложений, которые написаны для питона 2.7

Если **все** Ваши скрипты будут использовать 3.7, то проще всего, в каталоге */usr/bin/* выполнить команду:

```
sudo ln -s python3.7 python
```

Тогда **все** обращения к интерпретатору питона будут вызывать именно версию 3.7.

Но это довольно рискованный путь. В системе есть куча файлов на питоне и решать за всех - не стоит.

Если же Вам просто нужно, что бы конкретно **Ваши** программы исполнялись в версии 3.7, то пропишите это явно в каждой вашей программе в  первой строке так:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
```

и всё будет именно так, как Вы хотите.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё есть классный способ установки любой версии

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Он не перезапишет ваш существующий python3.8, который все еще имеет символическую ссылку как python3.
Вместо этого, чтобы запустить python3.5, запустите команду python3.5(или python3.Xдля любой другой версии python).
https://askubuntu.com/a/682875